# clang-cl on windows c++14 status

Tags: c++, windows, clang, c++14

Does clang-cl found here http://sourceforge.net/projects/clangonwin/files/MsvcBuild/3.7/ compiler has supported fully in accordance with the explanation of this page http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html ? What is the significant difference between clang.exe and clang-cl.exe, does c++14 implementation is affected between different of those variants? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Look like as of today [2017-01-20] , current clang implementation on windows might be stable enough for production use with msvc 2015+ only. For the other either libstdc++ or libc++  still work in progress by community voluntary efforts.